# Ranking sentences by positive and negative connotations

Tags: algorithm, nlp

I'm searching for an algorithm that ranks sentences by the connotations they carry. Ideally, this algorithm can return a larger value for sentences that carry more negative connotations. Any input will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a family of techniques called **[sentiment analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis)**.  I am not an expert on this topic, but a quick Google search turned up some links that might be useful for you.  For example, [this LingPipe project](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/sentiment/read-me.html) has what appears to be a sentiment analysis toolkit that you might be able to use as a starting point.

Hope this helps!